# Eclipse Helios (and probably all previous versions) uses only 192m when 512m is specified in -Xms and -Xmx Why?

Tags: eclipse, performance, memory, arguments, heap-memory

This is the vmargs string that I have added to the Windows Target for Ecipse.exe. In spite of adding this the memory that eclipse takes up in the Windows Task Manager is 192m. Why?

C:\Helios\eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

How to block 512m of memory on Eclipse startup itself?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can also try putting the settings in eclipse.ini. [See here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?).

[This page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm) claims that the default is 384M (for Indigo at least). Could you also try Indigo?